# What is the reason of Unsupported mail transport []. error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a hard time finding out the reason for this error. Even though I have done this configuration in a different setting which works, it does not work this time.

Getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentException  Unsupported mail transport [].
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php:175

I sent the form to the class, configured to send mail.
It returns that error, which the solution is not found anywhere else.

**config/mail.php**

```
return [

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
       
            'smtp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'myserver.myhost.com'),
                'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
                'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
                'username' => env('mail@mydomain.com'),
                'password' => env('mypassword'),
                'timeout' => null,
                'auth_mode' => null,
            ],
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
        /*
        'failover' => [
            'transport' => 'failover',
            'mailers' => [
                'smtp',
                'log',
            ],
        ],
        
    ],


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:h55EnKdo55xBM55knBOdA+kPT33axvHIwe31339T9yQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=myserver.myhost.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mail@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I would be glad to know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Please show your `config/mail.php` as well as the relevant .env variables, with any authentication variables hidden

Comment: Your smtp in mail.php has an extra layer (`'smtp' => ['smtp' => [...] ]`). Remove the extra array key.

Comment: The [boilerplate config/mail.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/mail.php) should give you an idea on what is going wrong here

Comment: @aynber absolutely right! my mistake. Should I still retain this question eventhough it was just a syntax error?

Comment: Nah, I doubt this is something that crops up very often